# How to show that $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb Z) = \langle A, B\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Show, that if $\mathbf{A}= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\ 0&1 \end{array} \right)$, $\mathbf{B}= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0&1\\ -1&0 \end{array} \right)$ and $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z}) := \{ \mathbf{C}\in\mathrm{M}(2\times 2;\mathbb{Z})\, |\,  \det(\mathbf{C}) = 1\}$ then $\langle\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}\rangle = \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

I found this exercise in a textbook for linear algebra in a chapter about the determinant, so it should be solved rather elementarily and without any deeper understanding of group theory ($\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ is defined only for the exercise). Showing $\langle\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}\rangle \subseteq \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ was easy but I got stuck with the opposite direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this result is true?  Something about it seems fishy to me.  Too may degrees of freedom in SL(2,Z) for my liking.

Comment: I compared again with the book and it looks correct to me but if you can show that it is false, I am also happy. :)

Comment: Just checking, is $\langle A,B \rangle = \{ A^m B^n : m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $ ?

Comment: $\langle\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}\rangle$ is surely "the group generated by **A** and **B**".

Comment: @David: If it helps, note the claimed statement is essentially "every invertible integer matrix is a product of integer elementary row operations", with a minor tweak to stay completely within determinant 1 rather than $\pm 1$.

Comment: It allows also the inverse:
$\langle\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \rangle := \{ \mathbf{C} | \exists i \in \mathbb{N} : \mathbf{C} = \mathbf{D}_1 \cdots \mathbf{D}_n with \mathbf{D}_i \in \{ \mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}, \mathbf{A}^{-1}, \mathbf{B}^{-1} \} \}$

Comment: @frank, Hurkyl Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what was meant by <A,B>. My apologies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The intuitive content is that the claimed statement roughly paraphrases into "every invertible integer matrix is a product of integer elementary row operations", with appropriate tweaks to the fact we want to stay within determinant 1 rather than $\pm 1$.

The proof of the claimed statement follows the same idea as the proof every invertible (real) matrix is a product of elementary matrices: show that elementary operations can row reduce any invertible matrix to the identity

The powers of $\mathbf{A}$ are precisely the elementary matrices that describe adding multiplies of the second row to the top row.

The powers of $\mathbf{BAB}^{3}$ are the elementary matrices that describe adding multiples of the top row to the second row.

Using these elementary row operations, any `2x2` integer matrix can be row reduced (think "Euclidean algorithm") to one of the following forms:

$$ \left( \begin{matrix} x & y \\ 0 & z \end{matrix} \right)
\qquad \left( \begin{matrix} x & y \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)
\qquad \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & x \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)
\qquad \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)
$$

with $0 \leq y < |z|$ in the first case, and $|x| > 0$ in all. If the original matrix was in $SL(2,\mathbf{Z})$, then only the first form is possible and we must have  either $x=z=1$, and thus $y=0$.