# About integral binary quadratic forms fixed by $\operatorname{GL_2(\mathbb Z)}$ matrices of order $3$

Tags: group-theory, matrices, representation-theory, quadratic-forms, group-actions

I am reading [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.4746v2) of Manjul Bhargava and Ariel Shnidman, and I want to prove this claim, which appear at the first paragraph of Theorem $14$:

> Up to $\operatorname{SL_2}(\mathbb Z)$ equivalence and scaling, there is only one integral binary quadratic form having an $\operatorname{SL_2}(\mathbb Z)$-automorphism of order three, namely $Q(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2$.

Now the pertinent definitions in order to understand the problem.

Consider the following action of $\operatorname{GL_2}(\mathbb Z)$ on the set of integral binary quadratic forms: for $\gamma\in$$\operatorname{GL_2}(\mathbb Z)$ and $f(x,y)=Px^2+Qxy+Ry^2$, with $P,Q,R\in\mathbb Z$, we define $(\gamma f)(x,y)=f\bigl((x,y)\gamma\bigr)$. Identifying each such $f$ with the triplet $(P,Q,R)^t$, we have that the triplet associated to $\gamma f$ is given by the matricial product

$$M_{\gamma}\,\cdot\begin{bmatrix} P\\ Q\\ R\end{bmatrix},\ \text{where}\ \
\gamma=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}\,\ \text{and}\ M_{\gamma}=\begin{bmatrix}
A^2 & AB    & B^2\\
2AC & AD+BC & 2BD\\
C^2 & CD    & D^2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

With these notations the authors' claim can be restated as follows:

> Suppose that $f=(P,Q,R)^t$ is fixed by $\gamma\in\operatorname{GL_2}(\mathbb Z)$ of order $3$ and $Q\ne0$. Show that there exist $\theta\in\operatorname{GL_2}(\mathbb Z)$ and $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\theta f=(n,n,n)^t.$

I have had a very bad time trying to prove this fact. Perhaps my understanding of the problem is wrong, but I honestly don't think so (I successfully completed the previous details of the paper).

My work so far: Let $a=A+D$ be the trace of $\gamma$. Since $\gamma^3=I$ then $\det\gamma=1$, so the characteristic polynomial of $\gamma$ is $X^2-aX+1$. Now

$$X^3-1=(X+a)(X^2-aX+1)+(a+1)\bigl[(a-1)X-1\bigr]\,,$$

and since $\gamma$ also satisfies $\gamma^3-I=0$, then after evaluating the equality above at $\gamma$ we obtain that either $a=-1$ or $(a-1)\gamma=I$; but $(a-1)\gamma=I$ implies $(a-1)^3=1$, that is $a=2$, and so $I=(a-1)\gamma=\gamma$, contradicting the fact that $\gamma$ has order $3$ in $\operatorname{GL_2}(\mathbb Z)$.

On the other hand $\gamma^{-1}$ also fixes $f$, so denoting $(P,Q,R)^t$ by $v$ we obtain $(M_{\gamma^{-1}}-M_\gamma)v=0$. Using the formula $\gamma^{-1}=\binom{\ \ D\ \ -B}{\!\!\!-C\ \ \ \ A}$ together with the equalities $AD-BC=1$ and $A+D=-1$ we get

$$\begin{align*}
M_{\gamma^{-1}}-M_{\gamma}=&\,\begin{bmatrix}
D^2  & -BD   &  B^2\\
-2CD & AD+BC & -2AB\\
C^2  & -AC   &  A^2
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
A^2 & AB    & B^2\\
2AC & AD+BC & 2BD\\
C^2 & CD    & D^2
\end{bmatrix}
\\[5mm]
=&\,\begin{bmatrix}
A-D & B & 0 \\
2C  & 0 & 2B\\
 0  & C & D-A
\end{bmatrix}\,,
\end{align*}$$

and so $v$ has the specific form $v=\frac Q{A-D}(-B,A-D,C)^t$.

Now I am stuck at this point: If $\theta=\binom{B\ \ \ 0}{D\ \ \ 1}$ then $M_\theta\cdot(n,n,n)^t=v$, where $n=\frac{-Q}{B(A-D)}$ (it is easy to see from the equalities $AD-BC=1$ and $A+D=-1$ that $B(A-D)\ne0$). The problem is, of course, that $n$ is not necessarily an integer and that $\theta$ not necessarily belong to $\operatorname{GL_2}(\mathbb Z)$. Changing $B$ by $1$ in $\theta$ does not work, because scaling the first row of $\theta$ amounts to a corresponding quadratic scaling at the first row of $M_\theta$, but keeping the same scaling at the second row of $M_\theta$, so the desired equality is not preserved.

I tried every possible matrix obtained from $\gamma$ with no success, so any help is welcomed!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modular group $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ [is presented by](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product#Presentation)
$$  \langle T,P | T^4 = P^3 = 1 \rangle,  $$
where we mean specific matrices
$$ T =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
  $$
and
$$ P =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
  $$
This is from page 9 in *Binary Quadratic Forms* by Duncan A. Buell. Proof takes a few pages.

Now, $P$ really is in the automorphism group for $x^2 + xy + y^2,$ since
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Next, I **believe** already (**confirmed by studiosus**, comment after answer as well as a **separate answer**) that any group element of order 3 is conjugate to $P$ or $P^2,$ of the form $gP g^{-1}$ for example. But then we simply absorb $g$ into the Gram/Hessian matrix for the form; that is, if
$$ (g^{-1})^TP^T g^T H gP g^{-1} = H,  $$ then
$$  P^T g^T H g P =  g^T H g,   $$ we rename
$$ G =  g^T H g  $$ to arrive at
$$   P^T G P =  G.  $$

Note that $g^T$ and $g^{-1}$ are not quite the same, and the expression $g^T H g$ is the correct expression for the Gram matrix of a new binary quadratic form; this new form is actually called "equivalent" to the original.

Finally, what things have $P$ in the automorphism group?
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & -1 \\
1 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2A & B \\
B & 2C
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2C & 2C-B \\
2C-B & 2A-2B+2C
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which give the equations
$$   2A = 2C, \; \; 2C-B = B, \; \; 2A-2B+2C = 2C,   $$
so actually $A=B=C.$

As far as I can tell that is it. It would be nice if someone with a more sure hand with generators and relations confirmed, or corrected, the part about elements of order 3 in the group.

Comment: Will: What you believe is correct. The key is that $PSL(2,Z)$ is the free product $Z_2*Z_3$ and, hence, every finite order element of the projective group is conjugate to one of the free factors. Serre's book "Trees" is probably the best reference.

Comment: @studiosus, thank you. I saw the bit about PSL in various places but decided to stick with the treatment in Buell. However, it is certainly true that PSL is, in the end, the natural group here.

Comment: Since the kernel of $SL(2,Z)\to PSL(2,Z)$ is of order 2, this does not affect the order 3 torsion: Every order 3 element in $SL(2,Z)$ is of the form you described.

Comment: @stud, thanks. I ordered Trees through the library; I am curious now, and do not remember this material at all well.

Comment: @stud, corrected the parts where I had too many inverses and not enough matrix transposes. Had forgotten what I was dealing with.

Comment: If you cannot wait for Serre's book (and it is a very delightful thing to read), see my answer below yours.

Comment: Regarding the presentation of $\operatorname{SL_2}(\mathbb Z)$, I found [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/159415/52816) nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit too long for a comment, it provides details for Will's answer: Consider a group $G$ which splits as a free product $G_1 * G_2$.

Theorem. Every finite order element is conjugate either into $G_1$ or into $G_2$.

Proof. The trick is to think of this not as an algebraic but a geometric problem. The free product decomposition of $G$ corresponds to a simplicial action of $G$ on a *Bass-Serre tree* $T$, which is a certain simplicial tree such that the vertex stabilizers are conjugates of $G_1$ and $G_2$ (there are exactly two $G$-orbits of vertices), and the edge-stabilizers are trivial. 
The construction of this tree is not hard at all, especially if you are a topologist familiar with van Kampen theorem (and Serre does not assume any knowledge of topology and proves everything from scratch by imitating Tits' BN pairs theory). As a topologist, I would consider a wedge $K$ of $K_1=K(G_1,1)$ and $K_2=K(G_2,1)$ (call $e$ the point where they are joined together) and look at its universal cover. Lifts of $K_1$ and $K_2$ are the vertices of the tree and lifts of $e$ are the edges. By van Kampen's theorem, $\pi_1(K)\cong G_1* G_2$. Everything else is elementary.

Now, if you have any finite-order element $g\in G$, its orbit in the vertex set of $T$ is finite and, hence, spans a finite subtree. It is an elementary argument nicely explained by Serre in his book that each group acting on a finite tree $S$ has a fixed point.  (Just keep removing all leaves of the  tree $S$ inductively until you have a fixed vertex left.) Therefore, such $g$ is conjugate into one of the subgroups $G_1$ or $G_2$.

Comment: good, and you included the more general result that seemed to be the correct thing.

Comment: The same OP asked later about a completely elementary proof for the original question above, it turns out there is such, not something i had thought about before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008067/an-annoying-pell-like-equation-related-to-a-binary-quadratic-form-problem/1009886#1009886